# Spring MVC - can't find referenced pointcut webLayer

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, web

Having an issue deploying a Spring 3.0.7 MVC web application to Tomcat via Eclipse and the WST plugin. Getting this error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/beans/appContext.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before
>   instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0'
>   while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0':
>   Initialization of bean failed; **nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced
>   pointcut webLayer**

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What does your pointcut expression look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got past this issue for now. Was using the wrong version of JDK for our project (1.7 instead of 1.6).

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating the pom to use aspectjrt-1.7 / aspectjweaver-1.7 for 1.7 java.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```